# Write R dataframe to Excel with column labels (and without using the Hmisc package)

Tags: r

I normally use the Hmisc package for column labels. Recently something changed in one of the dependencies (htmlTable) and the Hmisc package no longer installs properly.

Would you be able to recommend an alternative to exporting data frames to Excel in R with column labels? (ideally with base R without the use of any packages)

```
participantid <- c("001", "002")
visit <- c("Follow-up 1", "Follow-up 2")
df <- data.frame(participantid, visit)

var_labels <- c(
  participantid = "ID du participant", 
  visit = "Type de visite"
)

names(df) <- var_labels
```

I tried `names(df) <- var_labels`, but I do not actually want to replace the column name with a new value, I want to keep the column name the way it is `(participantid, visit)` but export the data with the column labels.

Thank you for your help,

Best wishes,

Moniek

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be exemplary in using valid names (i.e. without spaces and other non-character stuff) but now want to export to .xlsx with self-explaining names. You could use `setNames`.

```
> openxlsx::write.xlsx(df |> setNames(var_labels), 'foo.xlsx')
```

This way, the data gets exported using the *var_labels* but column names stay unchanged in the script (think that is what you want).

Check

```
> openxlsx::read.xlsx('foo.xlsx')
  ID.du.participant Type.de.visite
1               001    Follow-up 1
2               002    Follow-up 2
```

Note, that in .xlsx file no periods are printed.

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(participantid = c("001", "002"), visit = c("Follow-up 1", 
"Follow-up 2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
> var_labels <- c(
+   participantid = "ID du participant", 
+   visit = "Type de visite"
+ )
```

Answer (score 0):

Unknowingly how the `HMISC` output looks, find below a solution using `openxlsx2` writing multiple parts of a data object using attached attributes.

```r
# prepare data object with attribute
dat <- mtcars[seq_len(5), seq_len(5)]

labels <- c(
  "Miles/(US) gallon",
  "Number of cylinders",
  "Displacement (cu.in.)",
  "Gross horsepower",
  "Rear axle ratio"
)
attr(dat, "var.labels") <- labels


# custom function to add object with names, attributes and data
wb_add_data_with_attributes <- function(wb, x) {
  
  d_head <- wb_dims(cols = seq_along(dat), rows = 1)
  d_attr <- wb_dims(cols = seq_along(dat), rows = 2)
  d_data <- wb_dims(x = dat, from_row = 3)
  
  wb$clone()$
    add_data(dims = d_head, x = t(names(dat)), col_names = FALSE)$
    add_data(dims = d_attr, x = t(attr(dat, "var.labels")), col_names = FALSE)$
    add_data(dims = d_data, x = dat, col_names = FALSE)$
    add_font(dims = d_attr, color = wb_color("gray"), italic = TRUE)$
    add_cell_style(dims = d_attr, wrap_text = TRUE, vertical = "top")
  
}


# use the function
library(openxlsx2)
wb <- wb_workbook() |>
  wb_add_worksheet() |>
  wb_add_data_with_attributes(x = dat)

# watch the output
if (interactive()) wb$open()
```

[image: xlsx output with attributes in second row in gray and italic]